# how module/function is imported and how to know which keywords can be passed to built-in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, keyword

my first question is how a function is actually imported? i have below statement but show() function is not in bokeh.plotting but in another folder/module i.e. bokeh.io.showing then how is it imported using bokeh.plotting?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
```

Next question is : there are some keywords used in below function:

```
p = figure(width = 400, height = 400)
```

how can i know which keywords can be used here? i know if i use help function of python it can give some idea, but here it shows below only

```
figure(**kwargs)
    Create a new Figure for plotting.
```

nothing mentioned which are the keywords, that can be used in this function.

i opened source code and i got below:

```
def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):

        if 'plot_width' in kw and 'width' in kw:
            raise ValueError("Figure called with both 'plot_width' and 'width' supplied, supply only one")
        if 'plot_height' in kw and 'height' in kw:
            raise ValueError("Figure called with both 'plot_height' and 'height' supplied, supply only one")
        if 'height' in kw:
            kw['plot_height'] = kw.pop('height')
        if 'width' in kw:
            kw['plot_width'] = kw.pop('width')
```

so i have idea what can be used in this (width/height) but is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The very fact that it accepts **kwargs means that any keyword arguments you pass to the function is a valid argument.

This is generally done for wrappers of lower level implementations. 
This has the upside of not having to change the intermediate function (the one that you call - eg. bokeh.figure, which internally calls a matplotlib function  ).

The downside is that since it accepts any keyword arguments it is very difficult to maintain documentation for it since you would have to update the documentation when your intermediate function implementation changes, as well as when the underlying function's implementation changes.

This is a very common practice in a lot of data-science libraries ( though you will find some very popular libraries go through the painstaking process of maintaining documentation, eg. matplotlib).

In general, these intermediate functions generally accept (*args and **kwargs), since bokeh's figure does not accept it you cannot pass something like figure (1, 2, 3) to it.

If this is the first time you are encountering **something (unpacking of lists and dictionaries as arguments), this might be a good time to google search the same, as this is a very common occurrence.

As far as acceptable arguments go this is what I found:

Keyword Args:
[Figure Documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html)

active_drag (Either ( Auto , String , Instance ( Drag ) )) :
Which drag tool should initially be active. (default: ‘auto’)

active_inspect (Either ( Auto , String , Instance ( Inspection ), Seq ( Instance ( Inspection ) ) )) :
Which drag tool should initially be active. (default: ‘auto’)

active_scroll (Either ( Auto , String , Instance ( Scroll ) )) :
Which scroll tool should initially be active. (default: ‘auto’)

active_tap (Either ( Auto , String , Instance ( Tap ) )) :
Which tap tool should initially be active. (default: ‘auto’)

tools (Either ( String , Seq ( Either ( String , Instance ( Tool ) ) ) )) :
Tools the plot should start with. (default: ‘pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,save,reset,help’)

tooltips (Either ( String , List ( Tuple ( String , String ) ) )) :
An optional argument to configure tooltips for the Figure. This argument accepts the same values as the HoverTool.tooltips property. If a hover tool is specified in the tools argument, this value will override that hover tools tooltips value. If no hover tool is specified in the tools argument, then passing tooltips here will cause one to be created and added. (default: None)

x_axis_label (String ) :
A label for the x-axis. (default: ‘’)

x_axis_location (Enum ( VerticalLocation )) :
Where the x-axis should be located. (default: ‘below’)

x_axis_type (Either ( Auto , Enum ( Enumeration(linear, log, datetime, mercator) ) )) :
The type of the x-axis. (default: ‘auto’)

x_minor_ticks (Either ( Auto , Int )) :
Number of minor ticks between adjacent x-axis major ticks. (default: ‘auto’)

x_range (Any ) :
Customize the x-range of the plot. (default: None)

y_axis_label (String ) :
A label for the y-axis. (default: ‘’)

y_axis_location (Enum ( HorizontalLocation )) :
Where the y-axis should be located. (default: ‘left’)

y_axis_type (Either ( Auto , Enum ( Enumeration(linear, log, datetime, mercator) ) )) :
The type of the y-axis. (default: ‘auto’)

y_minor_ticks (Either ( Auto , Int )) :
Number of minor ticks between adjacent y-axis major ticks. (default: ‘auto’)

y_range (Any ) :
Customize the x-range of the plot. (default: None)

.

Comment: thanks for the answer! no this is not my first time to encounter **. I'm very well aware of this functionality. 'Any argument is valid'-- that's what i want to know what argument?

Answer (score 0):

the only way i found out to get the keywords is give some wrong keyword e.g. len. It will give us AttributeError along with the expected values. I ran this:

```
p = figure(width = 400, height = 400, background_fill_color='black',len=1)
```

it gave me the below:

```
AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'len' to Figure, possible attributes are above, align, aspect_ratio, aspect_scale, background, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_
fill_alpha, border_fill_color, center, css_classes, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, frame_height, frame_width, height, height_policy, hidpi, inner_height, inner_width, js_event_callb
acks, js_property_callbacks, left, lod_factor, lod_interval, lod_threshold, lod_timeout, margin, match_aspect, max_height, max_width, min_border, min_border_bottom, min_border_left, min_border
_right, min_border_top, min_height, min_width, name, outer_height, outer_width, outline_line_alpha, outline_line_cap, outline_line_color, outline_line_dash, outline_line_dash_offset, outline_l
ine_join, outline_line_width, output_backend, plot_height, plot_width, renderers, right, sizing_mode, subscribed_events, tags, title, title_location, toolbar, toolbar_location, toolbar_sticky,
 visible, width, width_policy, x_range, x_scale, y_range or y_scale
```

Not sure about my other question

edit :
i got the answer for my other question as well. import statement checks the init.py file and all the objects present in this file become accessable to use. In this case, show() was imported already.

```
from ..io import show; show
```